# Quiero crear una nueva variable a partir de que se cumplan dos condiciones de una ya existente en el mismo dataframe

Tags: r

La variable sit_irreg tiene estos valores

```
table(IPRE$SIT_IRREG)
```

```
    0     2     3     4 
29565   628  1794  2688
```

#he intentado esto

```
IPRE$STATUS<- cbind(IPRE$SIT_IRREG <= ifelse(IPRE$SIT_IRREG == "0" & IPRE$SIT_IRREG == "2", 1, 0))

IPRE$STATUS <- as.numeric(IPRE$STATUS)
```

```
class(IPRE$STATUS)

str(IPRE$STATUS)

table(IPRE$STATUS)
```

```
Y el resultado obtenido es:
[1] "numeric"
 num [1:34675] 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 ...
```

```
    0     1 
 5110 29565
```

#Cuando lo que busco es que salga para el 0 = 29565 + 628 = 33.193 y para el 1 = 1794 + 2688 = 4.482

```
   0     1 
 4482 33193
```

#¿No se que estoy haciendo mal? o lo que me falta en el código

Comment: Muchas gracias Samuel

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del `ifelse()` estás pidiendo que un valor cumpla ambas condiciones para que valga `0`. En lugar de usar `&` debes usar `|` porque quieres que cualquiera de esos valores te asocie al `0`.

```r
IPRE$STATUS<- cbind(IPRE$SIT_IRREG <= ifelse(IPRE$SIT_IRREG == "0" | IPRE$SIT_IRREG == "2", 1, 0))
```